# How to connect selenium grid on other machine?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Here what i have done :
1) created testcase in selenium IDE - TestNg format( local system)
2) altered in Eclipse 
3) Installed selenium grid on different machine (call ex 123.123.12.12 - linux)
4) Trying to run build.xml from local system 
  Default Selenium(host, port,browser, url)
Now its not connecting to 123.123.12.12 for runnin test case
what i have to do? Is it i am missing something or what is the procedure to achive this scenario?.
Thanks a lot.
By.
Mani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download Selenium Grid on the different machines that are needed.(One to run Hub (Hub) and other to launch the RC instances(RC1 & RC2))
   Example: 
         - Hub: 192.168.1.10 
         - RC1: 192.168.1.1 
         - RC2: 192.168.1.2
2. Launch the hub
   a.  Log in the machine you want to use as the hub (192.168.1.10).
   b.  Enter “ant launch-hub” command to launch the hub.
3. Launch RC1 :
   a.  log in the machine you want to launch the first RC instance (192.168.1.1)
   b.  enter “ant -Dport=5556 -Dhost=192.168.1.1 -DhubURL=http://192.168.1.10:4444 launch-remote-control”
4. Launch RC2 :
   a.  log in the machine you want to launch the first RC instance (192.168.1.2)
   b.  enter “ant -Dport=5556 -Dhost=192.168.1.2 - DhubURL=http://192.168.1.10:4444 launch-remote-control”
5. Enter http://192.168.1.10:4444/console link in address bar of browser and verify that ports are available.
6. Now run the tests.
   a.  Log in the host machine 192.168.1.10.
   b.  Enter “ant run-demo-in-parallel” command.

Comment: You also need to change "host" value in DefaultSelenium to point to hub host and port

Comment: @A.J Selenium grid manages the host and port on its own we dont have to set host and port only required base URL and set browser

Comment: like Selenium sel = new DefaultSelenium(BaseURL,*firefox)? in your code?